# Creating "SECRET" events through Facebook's graph api as a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I was able to create facebook events through graph api from **my facebook app** with this POST request:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/<MY_APP_ID>/events?
      start_time=2013-12-21T19%3A30%3A00
     &end_time=2013-1221T20%3A30%3A00
     &name=test+event
     &access_token=<MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

The response was a JSON, with the id of the newly created event.

After this i tried to create an other event with 'SECRET' privacy:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/<MY_APP_ID>/events?
      start_time=2013-12-21T19%3A30%3A00
     &end_time=2013-1221T20%3A30%3A00
     &name=test+secret+event
     &privacy_type=SECRET
     &access_token=<MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

The response here was also a JSON with the id of the created event.

After that I tried to list the events of my app:

```
 GET https://graph.facebook.com/<MY_APP_ID>/events/?access_token=<MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

In the response JSON, I can see only one, the not-secret event. The secret one is missing.

After this, i tried to get the details of the events one-by-one:

```
 GET https://graph.facebook.com/<EVENT_ID>/?access_token=<MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

In case of using the id of the non-secret event, the response contains all the details of that event, but when I'm using the id of the secret-event, it responds with an error msg:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Why am I not able to create SECRET (invite only) events with my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events can be created for three object types via the Graph API: Users, Pages and Applications, according to the Graph API [Events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) page:

> The User, Page, and Application objects have an events connection.

However, the Graph API Event page then only supplies links to the User and Page sections on how to create an Event (See Graph API Event page, Section Creating Events). There's no further reference to Application events and The [Application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) section doesn't mention an Events connection.

Out of the two linked-to Event types, creating an event with the `privacy_type` parameter is *only supported for Users*, not Pages:

Supported parameters for creating a User Event

> name, start_time, end_time, description, location, location_id, **privacy_type**

Source: [User Graph API details on Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events)

Supported parameters for Creating Page Event:

> name, start_time, end_time, description, location, location_id

Source: [Page Graph API details on Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events)

So my guess would be that Application follows the Page Event connection parameters but that this isn't properly documented.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen those in the docs, but my point is, this does not say anything about apps, just users and pages. As i said in the question, i was able to create an event as app (not as user or page). So in my case, the official documentation in incomplete. Page!=App, but it looks like they have the same behavior in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you created it as `SECRET`, you won't be able to retrieve that event using the app access token, because your app is not a user, and cannot see the event.

It's only visible to the user who created it and the other attendees - the user's access token should return the event, because the user access token acts with the same permissions as the user, and if they're marked as attending the event, they can see it

Comment: It seems you are right, but I still don't understand their reason about this. I'm able to create events as app. I can list those events as app (maybe because they are public). And finally I'm able to invite users to these events as an app. 
Why isn't possible to create an invite_only event, then list it (with app access token), and invite users to that?

Now as a workaround, I have to create an app-admin-user, authorize that, and do the event creation with that insted of the app. I'm not satisfied.

Comment: If you add user_events permissions to your app...I believe this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you shoud use one of these methods:

```
GET /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID
GET /EVENT_ID/attending/USER_ID
GET /EVENT_ID/maybe/USER_ID
GET /EVENT_ID/noreply/USER_ID
GET /EVENT_ID/declined/USER_ID
```

Or check out this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/